# Demonstrating the existence of a unique global minimum over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization

I'm trying to prove that the function $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, given by

$$Q(w)=|w|^{2n}-c\ln|w-w_0|^2$$

($c>0$ and $w_0>0$)
has a unique global minimum.

What I've tried so far: If one can show that any such global minimum must be real (e.g. by symmetry?), then restricting to the real axis and differentiating yields $Q'(x)=2n x^{2n-1}-\frac{2c}{x-w_0}$. Setting this equal to zero and multiplying through by $x-w_0$ yields a polynomial equation $0=x^{2n}-w_0 x^{2n-1}-\frac{c}{n}$ which, by Descartes' rule of signs, has precisely one negative and one positive root, say $x_0$ and $x_1$ respectively. Then looking at the second derivative of $Q$, one notices that $Q''(x)>0$, so each of these is a real minimum. This, however, isn't sufficient for either to be a minimum of $Q$ as a function on $\mathbb{C}$.

Graphing $Q$ in Mathematica suggests that the positive root, $x_1$, is a saddle point and the negative root, $x_0$, is the global minimum, but I haven't been able to demonstrate this rigorously.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Note that since Q is coercive the existence of a global minimum is assured. Now does it really help for the problem to reduce it to showing unicity I don't know.

Comment: note that if one fixes $|w|=r>0$ then $|w-w_0|$ is maximal when $w=-r$ so on the circle of radius $r$ there is only one global (wr circle) minimum at the negative value $-r$ so any global minimum must be real and negative